# how to kill an async task?

Tags: android

in fact I have a problem in my program.
I normally have to download files from an FTP server, and I have a button to do that when I click I have to download the file.
the problem is that when I click  several times.
the  task will not run, because I can not manage to kill asyntask.
here I have put a simple example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Connexion conx=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button bt= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (conx!=null){
                Log.i("voila", "we are here 1");
                conx.cancel(true);
                conx=new Connexion();
                conx.execute("73383_20130426_Tessenderlo_VBR_3.pdf");

            }else {
            conx=new Connexion();
            conx.execute("73383_20130426_Tessenderlo_VBR_3.pdf");}

        }
    });
}

class Connexion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    FTPClient mFTPClient;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("voila", "we are here 2");
         String chaine = params[0];
             try {
                    mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
                    mFTPClient.connect("site", 21);
                    Log.i("voila", "we are here 4");
                    if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                        boolean status = mFTPClient.login("user", "pass");
                        mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                        ftpDownload("/fromCIS/" +chaine ,
                                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + "/Fromcis/" + chaine);
                          mFTPClient.logout();  
                          mFTPClient.disconnect();

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
             return "zaki";    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("voila", "we are here onpost");
        conx=null;

    }

    public boolean ftpDownload(String srcFilePath, String desFilePath) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    desFilePath);
            ;
            status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);
            desFileStream.close();

            return status;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(e.getCause() + "", "download failed");
        }

        return status;
    }
}
}
```

what i must add in my code to fix my bug.
thank you very much for your help

thank you very much for your help i found the solution ,  the problem was in the retrivefile methode , i found the solution in this discussion [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706968/apache-commons-ftpclient-hanging)

Comment: Take a look at [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10882600/1289716)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `task.cancel(true);` but usually it works if you have a loop in your `doInBackground()` and check the value of `isCancelled` in it .**But** in your case there is not a loop.

Comment: and what i must to do in my case?

Comment: @zakzak Why do you click several times?

Comment: to download another file from server

Comment: @zakzak When user click on button,first check that dowloading previous file is completed or no?If no,notice to the user to wait more and try again later.

Comment: but the problem is that the program is bloket in ftpDownload method and y-the user can not wait for infinity time, i must to kill asyntask if the task is bloked

Answer (score 1):

in order to stom you got to do :

first- from your main thread:

```
conx.cancel(true);
```

and second- in your doInBackgroundMethod(String params..)

```
if(this.isCancelled()){
return "interrupt"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`task.cancel(true);` to stop an AsyncTask

Comment: This is only stops it. It doesn't kill the task.

Comment: And there are few other things to consider when cancelling an `AsyncTask`. See the answer by @hasanghaforian: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if (conx!=null){
      Log.i("voila", "we are here 1");
      conx.cancel(true);
      conx=new Connexion();
      conx.execute("73383_20130426_Tessenderlo_VBR_3.pdf");
}else {
      conx=new Connexion();
      conx.execute("73383_20130426_Tessenderlo_VBR_3.pdf");}
```

Just do:

```
// Kill any remaining tasks
conx = null;
// Start the new task
conx=new Connexion();
conx.execute("73383_20130426_Tessenderlo_VBR_3.pdf");
```

Comment: sorry  i used but it kill not the asyntask, and in several clik i have no answer from the program